# Should I put a semicolon in the href of a Javascript-only link?

Tags: javascript, html

Are there any advantages/disadvantages of

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="myFunc()">do myFunc</a>
```

over

```
<a href="javascript:" onclick="myFunc()">do myFunc</a>
```

Comment: isn't the `;` technically correct syntax?

Comment: I feel dumb for not trying this in jsfiddle :( I usually use `javascript:void(0);`

Comment: At a more meta level, there is a vast disadvantage (in terms of maintainability) to using inline javascript like ``onClick`` for events. While it requires more "work" upfront, using ``addEventListener`` would be a much better option for future sanity  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener).

Comment: I would use neither and create a button instead. Links should not be used for custom user interaction unless they also link to an actual page.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <a href="javascript:;" onclick="myFunc()">do myFunc</a>- 

      Will kill script execution


  <a href="javascript:" onclick="myFunc()">do myFunc</a>
       Execute Script
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/JZje5/

Comment: Just adding this link could be relevant to this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0

Comment: What do you mean? In your fiddle both seem to work the same way for me (after adding the missing "1" to the second function).

Comment: This answer is blatantly wrong and should be removed.